# PowerShell StreamReader Change Delimiter

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script to pull data from a database, but some of the fields contain commas and that is resulting in breaking up the fields because the StreamReader splits it up into fields by comma. How can I change the delimiter of how the data is split into it's fields?

```
$ConnectionString = "Data Source=server1; Database=Development; Trusted_Connection=True;";
$streamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter ".\output.csv"
$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $ConnectionString
$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConn
$sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Development.dbo.All_Opportunities WITH(NOLOCK)"
$sqlConn.Open();
$reader = $sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

# Initialze the array the hold the values
$array = @()
for ( $i = 0 ; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++ ) 
    { $array += @($i) }

# Write Header
$streamWriter.Write($reader.GetName(0))
for ( $i = 1; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i ++) 
{ $streamWriter.Write($("," + $reader.GetName($i))) }

$streamWriter.WriteLine("") # Close the header line

while ($reader.Read())
{
    # get the values;
    $fieldCount = $reader.GetValues($array);

    # add quotes if the values have a comma or double quote
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Length; $i++)
    {
    if ($array[$i] -match "`"|\S")
        {
            $array[$i] = '"' + $array[$i].Replace("`"", "`"`"").ToString() + '"';
        }
    }

    $newRow = [string]::Join(",", $array);

    $streamWriter.WriteLine($newRow)
}
$reader.Close();
$sqlConn.Close();
$streamWriter.Close();
```

Comment: I don't see a StreamReader anywhere.  I see a StreamWriter and an SqlDataReader.  Which do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this post to see if it helps your effort. It's for a text fiel, but could open you creativity to what is possible.

'stackoverflow.com/questions/14954437/streamreader-with-tab-delimited-text-file'

FYI, there is no delimiter type called 'field' 
Otherwise, for those columns that have a comma as part of the value, a common approach is either to double quote the value or escape it.